# iOS 11 large titles in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, uinavigationbar, ios11

How do I enable iOS 11 [prefersLargeTitles](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/2908999-preferslargetitles) throughout my Xamarin.Forms app?

[image]

I tried creating a custom renderer derived from `PageRenderer` for `NavigationPage`, setting:

```cs
ViewController.NavigationController.NavigationBar.PrefersLargeTitles = true;
```

This didn't have any effect, however.

Comment: No disrespect, but for someone with your reputation on SO, I'd expect a bit more effort than this. What have you tried?

Comment: I updated the question accordingly with my attempt. Since it had no effect, I didn't think it would be of much use, but just in case...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Voila

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NavigationPage), typeof(NavBarRenderer))]
namespace LargeTitleSample.iOS
{
    public class NavBarRenderer : NavigationRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            NavigationBar.PrefersLargeTitles = true;
        }
    }
}
```

You have to create a custom renderer for the `NavigationPage` inheriting the `NavigationRenderer`. Then set the `PrefersLargeTitles` property on the `NavigationBar` to true.

It seems that when you add some scrollable control to the page, it will automatically have to 'big to small' effect when scrolling up, at least for a `ListView`.

Working example repo is here: https://github.com/jfversluis/LargeTitleSample

Comment: Worked like a charm, but there isn't a small bug? I mean, on the bottom is appearing a white margin now

Comment: When scrolled up on the bottom of the screen you mean? I see.. Probably has something to do with the insets of some sort. I'll try to see if I can figure something out when I have a few minutes.

Comment: I ran into what may be a similar problem. The tab bar at the bottom of the page scrolls up when the text transitions from large to moving into the header.

Comment: The issue with the white space at the bottom is resolves in Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0.91635 (see [link](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/307295))

Answer (score 0):

For XAML:

```
<NavigationPage Title="..." xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core" ios:NavigationPage.PrefersLargeTitles="true">
```